# Issue with generic in Hibernate Template

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jakarta-ee, hql

I use Hibernate Template and have this code:

```
public List<Book> findBooksByName(String name) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Book WHERE name = ?", name);
}
```

I thought it looked good. But when I ran this code, I got an error:

```
[ERROR] incompatible types
[ERROR] required: java.util.List<com.model.Book>
[ERROR] found:    java.util.List<capture#1 of ?>
```

How can I fix it and get what I need? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you are extending a `HibernateDaoSupport` as explained in [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/). [`getHibernateTemplate()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#getHibernateTemplate()) will return a `HibernateTemplate` without any type specification. Which is all right because HibernateTemplate doesn't have type parameters.

So this find(...) method will return a `List` of Objects. The actual Hibernate code might return List of `HibernateProxy` instances. This `HibernateProxy` is an automatically generated subclass of your domain class, `Book` in this case.

So all you can do is to cast the result to the right kind of list:

```
public List<? extends Book> findBooksByName(String name) {
    return (List<? extends Book>) getHibernateTemplate().find("FROM Book WHERE name = ?", name);
}
```

This will make your `List` effectively read-only. This is the price that we pay for ORM convenience.